# Can I say which companies use my open source software?

Tags: open-source-software

I have written some open source (MIT License) software. I wrote the software for my own company **Company A**, that is legally registered with myself as the only employee. I only registered it so I could contract between jobs.

Recently I began a new full-time job in a senior position **Company B**, and we build software, as an agency, for some very large global companies **Company X**.

If I build software in **Company B** and use some of the open source libraries I built in **Company A**, can **Company A** say the open source software is used by **Company X**?

Essentially I want to create a public web page about the open source software, and I want to know if I can say it's used by **Company X**?

or something like: used in **Company X**'s **Product X**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you know that X is using your software thanks to your inside knowledge as an employee of B. As a rule it is not permitted for you to reveal this information because it is owned by B.

Its also a little tendentious to claim that X is using your software, since it is only doing so as a result of its incorporation by B. It would be more accurate to say that B is using your software.

Comment: Also maybe company B could take a dim view on you using your employment at B to promote your own software, and such behavior might lead to suspicious that you used the software not in company B's best interest but in you own's.

Comment: "*It would be more accurate to say that B is using your software*". The accuracy of your remark depends on the role or purpose of the libraries at issue. For instance, if the libraries are used for *building* the deliverable, then you are right. But if *running* the deliverable involves functionality from the libraries, then the OP's statement that company X is using his software is accurate.

Comment: @SJuan76 "*such behavior might lead to suspicious that you used the software not in company B's best interest but in you own's*". Your assumption is too speculative. It is in company B's best interest not to reinvent the wheel (given the associated cost), which the OP would preclude by re-using functionality he already implemented in his open source libraries.

Comment: It might have been in the company’s interest to have a different and more appropriate open source library used instead of the one the OP developed and is prone to promote. And, “company X is using it” implies company X choose it. That is not correct.